# Excel formula calculations into JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a formula into my excel sheet, now I am making that formula using JavaScript. I made a code exact like written on excel sheet but in JavaScript I am getting different result, I mean wrong result.

Excel formula

`= H4*((((1+H7)^H8-1)/H7)*(1+H7))`

JavaScript

```js
var contribute = 1000;
var cum_rate = 0.001666667;
var num_periods = 480;

var fvc = contribute * ((((1 + cum_rate) ^ num_periods - 1) / cum_rate) * (1 + cum_rate));

console.log(fvc);
```

Result of this calculations should be `735659.68` but here I am getting wrong result, can you guys help me out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the Excel formula to your question?

Comment: @ChrisG Just added

Comment: In JS, `^` is XOR. You need `Math.pow()`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2xcstovn/

Comment: @ChrisG Post as an answer?

Comment: try this -> https://github.com/fabiooshiro/xlsx-calc

Answer (score 0):

The karat doesn't mean exponent. You need to use `Math.pow(base, exp)` to evaluate the expression correctly:

```
var fvc = contribute*( ((Math.pow( (1+cum_rate), num_periods ) - 1)/cum_rate)*(1+cum_rate) )
```

Comment: Still not getting exact result

Comment: It’s `num_periods) - 1`, not `num_periods - 1)`.

Comment: Fixed. Amazing how pesky parens are to parse by hand.